# A python library to draw basic shapes?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I googled and what I find is libraries like turtle and tkinter, which are too good for what I want

I want shapes like these

```
print(" _______")
print("|1     2|")
print("|       |")
print("|3     4|")
print(" ------- ")
```

or like this

```
print(" _______")
print("|       |")
print("|       |")
print("|       |")
print(" ------- ")
```

do we have any library which makes it possible to make such shapes with different shapes and sizes,
Something simpler than turtle and matplotlib.

Comment: What do you mean with "too good for what I want"? What criteria do you have? Matplotlib can also draw shapes, but it is a good library in my opinion...

Comment: I am building a library for a data structure not in python, and I dont want a basic library to be dependent on an advanced one, also, libraries like turtle take a bit of more time to execute.

Comment: indeed, Matplotlib is great, but I feel such libraries are an overkill for the basic need of mine.
Also, Matplotlib takes a bit more of time than expected

Comment: Do you want text output or an image? Please be more specific.

Comment: Maybe the [graphics](https://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/) module is what you need...

Comment: @NiklasMertsch  i want it to be  light weight, so i want these primitive shapes to be printed on terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this library:
https://github.com/nschloe/termtables

This print tables on terminal.

Example:

```py
    import numpy
    import termtables as tt
    numpy.random.seed(0)
    data = numpy.random.rand(5, 2)

    string = tt.to_string(data)
```

Output:

```
┌────────────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ 0.5488135039273248 │ 0.7151893663724195 │
├────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│ 0.6027633760716439 │ 0.5448831829968969 │
├────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│ 0.4236547993389047 │ 0.6458941130666561 │
├────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│ 0.4375872112626925 │ 0.8917730007820798 │
├────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│ 0.9636627605010293 │ 0.3834415188257777 │
└────────────────────┴────────────────────┘
```

Another option would be:

https://github.com/zvibazak/termshape

Example:

Print a square:

```py
from tremshape import get_square
print(get_square(5))
```

```
* * * * *
*       *
*       *
*       *
* * * * *
```

Comment: I want shapes like triangle, rectangle, square
But as lightweight as these termtables you suggested

Comment: @SadafShafi see my update...